# Android Firebase: How can I create a notification channel that works with my existing notification system

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, channel, android-8.0-oreo

Thanks to a Spanish YouTube tutorial I was able to create a notifications system based on Google Firebase. But at the moment the notifications are only displayed on devices based on Android 7 and older.

This is the code that I created:

```
public class MiFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

    public static final String TAG = "NOTICIAS";

    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
    }

    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje recible de: " + from);

        if( remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

    }
```

After doing some research I found out that since Android O a notification channel is needed.

With the following I already tried to implement some code to make the channel work, but unfortunately without success. Can somebody help, please??

```
    public class NotificationUtils extends ContextWrapper {

        private NotificationManager mManager;
        public static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "mediengruppe.nova.notification.ANDROID";
        public static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME = "ANDROID CHANNEL";

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        public NotificationUtils(Context base) {
            super(base);
            createChannels();
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        public void createChannels() {

            // create android channel
            NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
                    ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
            androidChannel.enableLights(true);
            // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
            androidChannel.enableVibration(true);

            // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
            androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);


        }

        private NotificationManager getManager() {
            if (mManager == null) {
                mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            }
            return mManager;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so it works for another Android except Android O?

Comment: it works for Android 7 and older, but not for the modern versions (everything since Android O)

Comment: May I know where did you implement the Notification inside the MiFirebaseMessagingService ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly sure what you mean... The code in the first box is everything that makes it work for older Android versions. The tutorial for this can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTQ4d3ZUS8g

Or do you refer to code from another file like for example the main_activity? If so, I will send it to you!